# OS X 10 Excel for Mac 2016 Startup Folder

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

How does one set a Startup Folder for Excel for Mac 2016?  I have looked everywhere and, unlike the previous version of Excel for the Mac, can't find any documentation for the 2016 version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you want is in

Excel → Preferences → General → *At startup open all files in* ...